# ASP.NET - Outputting Errors to Browser in Production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I am debugging an app that is working fine in development but erring in production.

Browser is displaying a pretty message:
*"Sorry an error occurred while processing your request"*

I am new to .NET, coming from RoR. In Rails, you can set up the config to display errors to the browser, in the production environment.

Is there a similar feature in .NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In web config, just turn off custom errors

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
```